# Unresolved external symbol when trying to use singleton

Tags: c++, oop, singleton

I am getting this error:

"LNK2001    unresolved external symbol "private: static class Example * Example::instance" (?instance@Example@@0PAV1@A)"

when I run the following code:

Example.h

```
class Example
{
private:

  static Example* instance;
  Example(){}

public:

  static Example* Instance();
};
```

Example.cpp

```
Example* Example::Instance()
{
    if (!instance)
    {
        instance = new Example;
    }

    return instance;
}
```

Entity.h

```
class Entity
{
private:

    Example* example;

public:

    Entity();
    Example* getExample();
};
```

Entity.cpp

```
Entity::Entity() : example(Example::Instance())
{
}

Example* Entity::getExample()
{
    return example;
}
```

I think it has something to do with this line:

```
Entity::Entity() : example(Example::Instance())
```

But why does this cause a problem?

Comment: No it has to do with `static Example* instance;`. That's only a *declaration*, and you never *define* the `instance` variable anywhere. There's quite a few duplicates around here and on the Internet in general.

Comment: The pattern you are using is obsolete with C++11. `class singleton { private: singleton(); // Disallow instantiation outside of the class. singleton(singleton const &) = delete; operator=(singleton const &) = delete; public: static auto instance() { static singleton s; return &s; } };`

Comment: Thanks guys. I was able to fix my problem using your tips.